# Unable to run SAST stage inside gitlab-ci, says "docker: command not found"

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

**Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

include:
  - template: Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - upload

variables:
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:test
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  SAST_DISABLE_DIND: "true"

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  tags:
    - xlp2

sast:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - xlp2 
  allow_failure: true
  artifacts:
    paths: [gl-sast-report.json]
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run -d --name test_container $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - sleep 60
    - if ! docker ps -q -f status=running -f name=test_container; then
        echo "Container is not running.";
        exit 1;
      fi
    - docker rm -f test_container
    - docker rmi $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  dependencies:
    - build
  tags:
    - xlp2

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "devops"'
  dependencies:
    - build
  tags:
    - xlp2

send-reports:
  stage: upload
  tags: 
    - xlp2
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json
  script: |
    cat gl-sast-report.json
    content=$(cat gl-sast-report.json)
    if [ "${content}" = "[]" ]
    then
      echo " all good! Your source code looks amazing"
    else
      echo " ouch! There are some vulnerabilities"
    fi
```

**When i push the changes to gitlab,**

[image]

[image]

***The error log from gitlab job**
Using docker image sha256:ba9ee6b6f770d81051bda6381f74246c730b618ea93eb54b215cbeb862aff0ee for registry.gitlab.com/security-products/semgrep:3 with digest registry.gitlab.com/security-products/semgrep@sha256:258ceebede48e14d7eb3759018537b4602950a93d146c1d7b9c240eebabf35e3 ...
$ docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
/bin/sh: eval: line 142: docker: not found
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: gl-sast-report.json: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory
ERROR: No files to upload

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127*

**what i tried?**

1. variables:
   SAST_DISABLE_DIND: "true"
2. include:

   - template: Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
3. include:

   - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

**Thanks to @sytech, the fix is working 100%**

after successful run i see the below json report, where it says some vulnerabilities? But i don't understand what exactly the vulnerability is?

[image]

Comment: It seems like your global `before_script:` is unintentionally impacting the included job from the sast template. You should try to either remove the `before_script:` from the global key or use [`inherit:default:false`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#inherit) in the job that is failing.

Comment: wow.. i did use inherit:default:false and this works like a charm, thank you very much, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Your global default `before_script` seems to be accidentally interfering with the included sast job. This is because the sast job uses an image that does not have `docker` so, this causes an error in that job.

To avoid this, you can add [`inherit:default:false`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#inherit) to the job that is failing. This will prevent it from inheriting the global default `before_script:`.

Alternatively, you can forego using the global default key (setting `before_script:` on each job that needs it) and that will also fix it.